# Problema con cambio de clase en un carrousel

Tags: javascript

Estoy teniendo un problema con un código para un carrousel.. si bien pude solucionarlo moviendo un forEach de lugar, no puedo lograr entender por qué no funciona bien el código que habia escrito antes. No logro comprender el efecto que produce que luego del primer intervalo la clase active siempre quede en el elemento de la posicion 1.

CODIGO QUE NO FUNCIONA BIEN:

```
 setInterval(() => {
    let contain;
    carrouselBtns.forEach((btn, i) => {
      contain = btn.classList.contains("carrousel__point--active");
      if (!contain) {
        let moving = i * -50;
        carrousel.style.transform = `translateX(${moving}%)`;
        carrouselBtns.forEach((btn) => {
          btn.classList.toggle("carrousel__point--active");
        });
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
```

CODIGO QUE FUNCIONA BIEN:

```
setInterval(() => {
  let contain;
    carrouselBtns.forEach((btn, i) => {
      contain = btn.classList.contains("carrousel__point--active");
      if (!contain) {
        let moving = i * -50;
        carrousel.style.transform = `translateX(${moving}%)`;
      }
    });
    carrouselBtns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.toggle("carrousel__point--active");
    });
}, 3000);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen trato de indagar porque en el primer forEach padre el carrousel se mueve a la imagen siguiente.. luego en el segundo intervalo.. ya no lo hace, quedando la clase active siempre en la posición 1.

Comment: Coloca un [MRE] ?? (Cuando edites tu pregunta hay un icono `<>` lo presionas y ahí en cada sección ingresas el CSS, JS y HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré comprender el efecto. (lo dejo igualmente para el que pueda tener un problema similar).

**El primer intervalo** funciona bien... y las clases quedan efectivamente:

```
0 - 1:A
```

**En el segundo intervalo** el primer botón ya no tiene la clase por lo que entra al if... al entrar togglea la clase y queda:

```
0:A - 1
```

El problema es cuando ahora forEach pasa al segundo botón que por el toggle que acaba de ejecutarse TAMPOCO TIENE LA CLASE... por lo tanto vuelve a entrar al if y se vuelve a togglear la clase y queda de nuevo como:

```
0 - 1:A (exactamente como en el intervalo anterior)
```

Y seguirá pasando con los intervalos que vengan... siempre queda como `0 - 1:A`
me tomó **2:17hs** entenderlo jajajaj que lo tiró!!